# How to load a pdf file in ipad using sencha?

Tags: pdf, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How to load a pdf file in ipad using sencha?

I have tried the following methods:

```
 html:'<div id="scroller" style="width:99%;overflow:scroll;">' +
            '<img style="width:100%;overflow:scroll;"' +
               'src="resources/pdfFiles/help.pdf">' +
               '</img></div>'
```

and

```
 html:'<div id="scroller" style="width:99%;overflow:scroll;">' +
            '<iframe style="width:100%;overflow:scroll;"' +
               'src="resources/pdfFiles/help.pdf">' +
               '</iframe></div>'
```

and

```
html:'<div style="height:99%;width:99%;overflow:scroll;">' +
       '<embed type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%" src="resources/pdfFiles/help.pdf" /></div>'
```

and

```
  html:'<object data="resources/pdfFiles/help.pdf" TYPE="application/x-pdf" width="100%" height="100%" </object>'
```

iframe works fine in chrome browser and opens up the pdf. But in ipad it opens up blank. img tag opens up only the first page of the pdf in ipad. How to load the entire pdf in ipad on tap of a button? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Sencha Touch applications do NOT work well with `iframe`, especially when pdf is embedded in it.

You had better open up as a new link in browser and let the browser do the remaining tasks.

Here is a discussion on official forum: [Displaying PDF and other non-HTML content in Sencha Touch 2](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?211954-Displaying-PDF-s-and-other-non-HTML-content-in-a-Sencha-Touch-App)